Why do three random walkers on $\mathbb Z$ meet infinitely often?
A paper of Dvoretzky and Erdős refers to the fact that three random walkers independently undertaking a simple symmetric random walk on $\mathbb Z$ will meet infinitely often with probability $1$, but that this is no longer true if there are four (see page 367 of [1]).
In the three-walker case, I believe I can show that the probability that the three walkers meet at a given point infinitely often is $0$, though I don't see how to specialise this to the general case. Does anyone have a reference for a proof of the claim?

[1] Dvoretzky, P. Erdős: Some problems on random walk in space, Proceedings of the Second Berkeley Symposium on Mathematical Statistics and Probability, 1950 , pp. 353--367, University of California Press, Berkeley and Los Angeles, 1951

I assume the intention is that the three random walkers walk independently.
These three walkers on $\Bbb Z$ can collectively be considered a single random walker on $\Bbb Z^3$, where each of the eight steps $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ are chosen with probability $\frac18$. Asking that the three walkers meet at a particular point is a question about transience on this three-dimensional lattice, and so it is indeed true that the probability of them meeting at a particular point infinitely often is $0$.
However, when we're interested in the three walkers meeting (anywhere) infinitely often, that corresponds to the three-dimensional walker visiting the line $x=y=z$ infinitely often. If we squint at this three-dimensional lattice with its one-dimensional target sublattice, it starts to look like a two-dimensional random walk that would therefore be recurrent.
More rigorously, let's consider the lattice obtained when taking the quotient of $\Bbb R^3$ by the line $x=y=z$, or equivalently when projecting $\Bbb R^3$ onto the hyperplane $H=\{x+y+z=0\}$ orthogonal to that line; this projection sends $(x,y,z)$ to $\bigl( x-\frac{x+y+z}3,y-\frac{x+y+z}3,z-\frac{x+y+z}3 \bigr)$. The image of $\Bbb Z^3$ under this quotient map is a lattice $L$ contained in $H$ (it's somewhere between $\Bbb Z^3\cap H$ and $(\frac13\Bbb Z)^3\cap H$). Now the single (formerly three-dimensional) random walker is doing a random walk on $L$, with eight possible steps (projections of the three-dimensional steps)
$$
\pm(0,0,0),\, \pm(\tfrac23,\tfrac23,-\tfrac43),\, \pm(\tfrac23,-\tfrac43,\tfrac23),\, \pm(-\tfrac43,\tfrac23,\tfrac23)
$$
each with probability $\frac18$. One can check that this is a symmetric random walk on this two-dimensional lattice of the type that classical theorems apply to, and therefore it is recurrent: it returns to the origin infinitely often, which means that the three-dimensional walker returns to the line $x=y=z$ infinitely often.
(A similar analysis confirms transience in the case of four or more one-dimensional random walkers.)

Another way to reduce this to a 2D random walk is to imagine that one of the three walkers carries the origin of the number line, and track the other two walkers relative to this origin. Then the other two walkers change position, relative to this origin, by an ordered pair sampled from the multiset ${(0,0), (0,2), (2,0), (2,2), (0,0), (0,-2), (-2,0), (-2,-2)}$, which is yet another two-dimensional random walk.
